# Does Linux GZip Zip the File in Place or create a new file

Tags: linux, gzip

I have a 1.5TB size text file that I need to gzip down, the current drive it is on has little to no space left.  I have another drive with 400G left on it. My question is, if I gzip the file, will it require more space on the drive that it resides?  Or can I direct the output to the drive with available space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
gzip --stdout textfile > /path/to/spacious/filesystem/textfile.gz
```